# Bundler: How can I configure a group of gems so that they are not downloaded in Production?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, bundler

How can I configure a group of gems so that they are not downloaded in Production?

So if I have this Gemfile:

```
source 'http://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails'
gem 'facebook_oauth'      
gem 'koala', '>=1.0.0.rc'
gem "jquery-rails"
gem 'faraday', '0.5.7'

group :development, :test do
  gem "rspec-rails", ">= 2.0.0" 
  gem "steak" 
  gem 'launchy'
  gem "capybara"
  gem 'akephalos', :git => 'git://github.com/Nerian/akephalos.git'
end
```

The gems marked with :development and :test should not be downloaded in Production.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to run your `bundler install` with the option `--without`

```
bundler install --without development test
```

---

**update**
*In regards to Heroku:*

```
heroku config:add BUNDLE_WITHOUT="development:test"
```

You can find more Heroku + Bundler info [here](http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/bundler)

Comment: Nice, but the context of this app is Heroku. Do you know how can I set that in Heroku?

Answer (score 0):

In deployment via Capistrano:

```
# config/deploy.rb

set :bundle_without, [:development, :test, :your_custom_group]
```